# Connecting YouTube Video Account with Google+ page

Tags: youtube, google-plus

Have had a YouTube business video page for years now (pre-Google Plus) and along the way created a Google+ page and built it up.  Now we have a separate Google+ and YouTube page and I need to connect the YouTube account to this Google+ account.

Is it possible to connect a YouTube account to a different Google+ account, so that when you post a YouTube video, it shows up on the right Google+ page, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect channels to Google+ and brand pages and move connections via https://www.youtube.com/account_tranfer_channel